# Unable to use Python to connect to mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I am attempting a basic MySQL connection program using Python. The code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_hi('PyCharm')

    print("Connecting to database.")
    mysqldb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="username",
        password="password"
    )
    print(mysqldb)
```

Running this simple program results in the following error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (61 Connection refused).
```

- I am able to connect with mysql (via terminal) normally: `mysql -u username -p`
- Running `netstat -tln | grep 3306` returns empty.

```
mysql> show global variables like '%port%';
    +--------------------------+-------+
    | Variable_name            | Value |
    +--------------------------+-------+
    | admin_port               | 33062 |
    | large_files_support      | ON    |
    | mysqlx_port              | 33060 |
    | mysqlx_port_open_timeout | 0     |
    | port                     | 0     |
    | report_port              | 0     |
```

What am I missing? How do I solve this? I am on an M1 Mac, if that helps.

Edit:
@BillKarwin: Running "select @@networking;" returns:

| @@skip_networking |
| --- |
| 1 |

Comment: Can you please query `SELECT @@skip_networking;` in your MySQL client and report what it returns?

Comment: @BillKarwin: This is what it returns.  

| @@skip_networking |
+-------------------+
|                 1 |
+-------------------+

Comment: Sorry, the response is not formatting well. Let me add to the question too.

Answer (score 0):

The Python connector uses TCP/IP, not the UNIX socket, even if you connect locally.

Since you confirmed that `skip_networking` is enabled, and `port` is 0, this explains why you can't connect using TCP/IP.

I guess you are using a JetBrains IDE to connect to MySQL, because of your line of code that references PyCharm. Here's a documentation page for connecting a JetBrains IDE to MySQL using UNIX sockets: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-unix-sockets.html

Or else you must edit your MySQL Server's `my.cnf` file and change the `skip_networking=1` line. Set it to 0 or OFF. Cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_skip_networking